# How to submit the selected option of a dropdown list?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have the following code to show a list to users to select an option, it correctly shows the list options but when an option is selected and the form is submitted, it runs into following error.

Error

```
 Caused by: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'developerID': The requested list key 
 'listOfdevelopers' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. 
 Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

JSP

```
 <s:form ...>
  <s:select name="developerID"
                      label="developerID"
                      list="listOfdevelopers"
                      value="%{development.developerID}"
                      />
 </s:form>
```

My code

```
....
private Map listOfdevelopers;
private Development development = new Development();

public Map getListOfdevelopers() {
    return listOfdevelopers;
}

public void setListOfdevelopers(Map listOfdevelopers) {
    this.listOfdevelopers = listOfdevelopers;
}

public Development getDevelopment() {
    return development;
}

public void setDevelopment(Development development) {
    this.development = development;
}

@Override
public Development getModel() {
    return this.development;
}
...
```

Comment: You are not populating your map on submit.

Comment: Is there the code where you are populating the collection?

Comment: @Daniel Morgan can u show struts.xml

Comment: did you configured any interceptors in struts.xml

Comment: How do you access the page with the form initially? It must go through an action, and the list of developers must be initialized-please show the code that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:select list="listOfdevelopers"
                        id="developerID"
                         name="developerID"
                             label="developerID"
                             headerKey=""
                              headerValue="Please choose one."
                            value="%{development.developerID}"
                      />
```

example

```
<s:select list="genderList"
          id="gender"
          name="gender"
          cssClass="listmenu validate-selection"
          listKey="name"
          listValue="details"
          headerKey=""
          value="userInfo.userPersonalInfo.gender"
          headerValue="Please choose one."
          ></s:select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually problem is with your **s:select**, here value tag is causing the problem.

try this

```
    <s:select list="listOfdevelopers" 
              name="developerID"
              headerKey="-1" 
              headerValue="Select Any Developer"
              listKey="developerID"               // your collection_element
              listValue="developer_name"          // your collection_element
    />
```

Comment: How that is answering OP question?

Comment: i dont get you, will you elaborate what are you trying to say

Comment: That this is not the answer to the question. The error says it because of `listOfdevelopers` and not because of value.

Comment: But the issue is explicitly with the list, on form render. Perhaps you could explain how not addressing that answers the question.